# Checking equality of row elements in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `mxn`. I want to construct a vector B of dimension `mx1` such that `B(i)=1` if all elements of `A(i,:)` are equal and `0` otherwise. Any suggestion? E.g.

```
A=[1 2 3; 9 9 9; 2 2 2; 1 1 4]
B=[0;1;1;0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with [`diff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) -

```
B = all(diff(A,[],2)==0,2)
```

Or With [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
B = all(bsxfun(@eq,A,A(:,1)),2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another example that's a bit more obfuscated, but also does the job:

```
B = sum(histc(A,unique(A),2) ~= 0, 2) == 1;
```

So how does this work?  [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) counts the frequency or occurrence of numbers in a dataset.  What's cool about `histc` is that we can compute the frequency along a dimension independently, so what we can do is calculate the frequency of values along each row of the matrix `A` separately.  The first parameter to `histc` is the matrix you want to compute the frequency of values of.  The second parameter denotes the edges, or which values you are looking at in your matrix that you want to compute the frequencies of.  We can specify all possible values by using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) on the entire matrix.  The next parameter is the dimension we want to operate on, and I want to work along all of the columns so `2` is specified.

The result from `histc` will give us a `M x N` matrix where `M` is the total number of rows in our matrix `A` and `N` is the total number of unique values in `A`.  Next, if a row contains all equal values, there should be only **one** value in this row where all of the values were binned at this location where the rest of the values are zero.  As such, we determine which values in this matrix are non-zero and store this into a result matrix, then [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) along the columns of the result matrix and see if each row has a sum of 1.  If it does, then this row of `A` qualifies as having all of the same values.

---

Certainly not as efficient as Divakar's `diff` and `bsxfun` method, but an alternative since he took the two methods I would have used :P

Comment: You guys are leaving very few options unexplored! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Some more alternatives:

```
B = var(A,[],2)==0;
B = max(A,[],2)==min(A,[],2)
```

Comment: OH.  Very very clever the `max/min` check. +1.  The variance too!  One could even explore the `mean` too:  `B = mean(A, [], 2) == A(:,1);` notwithstanding floating point errors.